# curses bkgd do not correctly work in PuTTY

Tags: python, putty, curses

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding = utf-8 -*-

import curses

def main(stdscr):
    # Color Pair
    curses.use_default_colors()
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_CYAN,  curses.COLOR_BLUE)
    curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLUE)
    curses.init_pair(3, curses.COLOR_CYAN,  curses.COLOR_BLACK)

    height,width = stdscr.getmaxyx()

    stdscr.bkgd(" ", curses.color_pair(2) )
    stdscr.clear()

    # Print
    stdscr.addstr("널 향한 설레임을 오늘부터 우리는\n", curses.A_BOLD)
    stdscr.addstr("꿈꾸며 기도하는 오늘부터 우리는 저 바람에\n", curses.A_BOLD)
    stdscr.addstr("노을 빛 내 맘을 실어 보낼게\n", curses.A_BOLD)
    stdscr.addstr("그리운 마음이 모여서 내리는\n", curses.A_BOLD)

    stdscr.addstr(5, 0, "Me gustas tu gustas tu\n", curses.A_BOLD | curses.color_pair(1) )
    stdscr.addstr("su tu tu ru 좋아해요\n", curses.A_BOLD | curses.color_pair(1) )
    stdscr.addstr("gustas tu su tu ru ru\n", curses.A_BOLD | curses.color_pair(1) )

    stdscr.addstr(9, 2, "+----+")
    stdscr.addstr(10, 2, "|    |")
    stdscr.addstr(10, 3, "가")

    stdscr.addstr(14, 2, "%d %d" % (width, height) )

    stdscr.addstr(12, 2, "Press any key...")

    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Displayed in PuTTY: [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brbbD.png)

Displayed in ConEmu: [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZTDa.png)

Displayed in MATE Terminal: [image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWwiv.png)

What is the method to be correctly displayed in PuTTY?

Comment: The first/last should be similar if you're using `TERM=xterm` and running on the same machine.  The second one's never been vetted, so it's out of scope.